# Performance of two alternative functions that compute least divisor

Tags: performance, algorithm, haskell, primes

In the book "*The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming*", the authors present two alternative ways of finding the least divisor `k` of a number `n` with `k > 1`, claiming that the second version is much faster than the first one. I have problems understanding why (I am a beginnner).

Here is the first version (page 10):

```
ld :: Integer -> Integer -- finds the smallest divisor of n which is > 1
ld n = ldf 2 n

ldf :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
ldf k n | n `rem` k == 0 = k
        | k ^ 2 > n      = n
        | otherwise      = ldf (k + 1) n
```

If I understand this correctly, the `ld` function basically ends up iterating through all integers in the interval `[2..sqrt(n)]` and stops as soon as one of them divides `n`, returning it as the result.

The second version, which the authors claim to be much faster, goes like this (page 23):

```
ldp :: Integer -> Integer -- finds the smallest divisor of n which is > 1
ldp n = ldpf allPrimes n

ldpf :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer
ldpf (p:ps) n | rem n p == 0 = p
              | p ^ 2 > n    = n
              | otherwise    = ldpf ps n

allPrimes :: [Integer]
allPrimes = 2 : filter isPrime [3..]

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n | n < 1     = error "Not a positive integer"
          | n == 1    = False
          | otherwise = ldp n == n
```

The authors claim that this version is faster because it iterates only through the list of *primes* within the interval `2..sqrt(n)`, instead of iterating through all numbers in that range.

However, this argument doesn't convince me: the recursive function `ldpf` is eating one by one the numbers from the list of primes `allPrimes`. This list is generated by doing `filter` on the list of all integers.

So unless I am missing something, this second version ends up iterating through all numbers within the interval `2..sqrt(n)` too, but for each number it first checks whether it is prime (a relatively expensive operation), and if so, it checks whether it divides `n` (a relatively cheap one).

I would say that just checking whether `k` divides `n` for each `k` should be faster. Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Could be that compiler magic applies to isPrime that makes it faster in the majority case than you'd expect.

Comment: Indeed. As in [Petr Pudlák's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21971525/1598537), for single use, the naive algorithm should beat the primes-only one. Any subsequent use at or below previous use will be faster, because `primes` is a constant applicative form (CAF) and will be memoised. In fact the `primes` list isn't the fastest algorithm, but at least it avoids the usual "unfaithful" seive of Eratosthenes multiple-removals problem. Read [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) if you want to find primes faster.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, you I'd use `n*n` rather than `n^2`, since I don't trust the compiler to do that for me.

Comment: Would leaving out the obvious non-primes make the first variant significatly more competitive relative to the second? I.e., check k=2,3,5 and then add alternatively 2 and 4 to k to iterate through the numbers 6j-1 and 6j+1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main advantage of the second solution is that you compute the list of primes `allPrimes` only once. Thanks to lazy evaluation, each call computes just the primes it needs, or reuses the ones that have been already computed. So the expensive part is computed only once and then just reused.

For computing the least divisor of just a single number, the first version is indeed more efficient. But try running `ldp` and `ld` for all numbers between let's say 1 and 100000 and you'll see the difference.

Comment: `For computing the least divisor of just a single number, the first version is indeed more efficient` - OK, so this is basically all I'm concerned with. I do understand that memoizing and other optimizations could make the second algorithm run faster in a computation such as `sum $ map ldp [1..1000000]`, where previously computed results can be reused, but this context is not obvious when the authors write "*By running the program `primes2` against `primes1` it is easy to check that `primes2` is much faster*". Anyway, I'm marking this answer as accepted. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

haskell is unknown for me so without proper measurements of booth version I can only assume that the claims are right. In that case the reasons can be:

1.primes are precomputed in some array

- then isprime? is not time expensive

2.primes are computed on the run (and memoizing)

- from start will be the first version faster
- but continuous use will make the second version faster (especially for bigger n)

3.primes are computed on the run (and not memoizing)

- as DeadMG mentioned
- compiler optimizations+CPU caching can sometimes feel like memoizing effect up to a point
- in that case version 2 will be overall faster
- but if you continue to use bigger and bigger n and small ones all the time
- after reaching cache  invalidation point it will slow down even more then version 1

4.this is just a guess

- is it possible for your compiler to convert recursion
- like single integer iteration through list or range
- to loop ? (most recursions of this type can be converted to loop anyway)
- that could explain all ...
- no recursion calls overhead
- no heap trashing

[Note]

- as I wrote above I am not haskell user so treat this answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regardless of what the reason is for the alleged difference in performance (I haven't done any proper benchmark either), I think the authors' explanation is misleading at best. They seam to imply that the advantage is obviously due to the more clever algorithm (you process a smaller list of primes rather than a longer list of all integers), but completely gloss over the fact that the list of primes is itself generated on-demand by filtering the list of all integers. *[continues...]*

Comment: *[...follows]* While I do understand that compiler magic or memoizing or even CPU caching could play a role, this is not obvious and the authors do not hint at any of those things. *Sad face*

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this, the division operation isn't as expensive as you might think for the divisor of 2, this makes for half of `allPrimes` filtered out numbers to be checked for "shift right 1 bit" which is as simple as a computing operation can be, while the first algorithm will perform a relatively expensive true division by the whole of the number. Say if the possible divisor is 1956, it will be filtered out of `allPrimes` by executing the very first test at almost no cost (shift right will return zero - divisible by 2) while dividing a say `2^4253-1` by 1956 is already senseless, as it's not divisible by 2, and in case of really big numbers divisions take a lot of time, and at least half of them (or say 5/6, for divisors 2 and 3) are useless. Also `allPrimes` is a cached list, thus checking the next integer for a prime to be included in `allPrimes` uses only verified primes, so the primality test isn't extremely expensive even for the actual prime number. This combined gives the second method advantage.